# Finding question with an interesting comment about ReLU activation functions?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, comment, search

A few months ago, I read an interesting comment by user shimao to a question, which linked to a YouTube video where some lecturer (a mathematician, I think) showed how ReLU activations **don't** solve the vanishing gradient problem (contrary to "popular" belief), but ResNets do, and went on to prove the second result for linear residual connection networks. I tried to find the question, but searching for things like "ReLU solve vanishing gradient" or even just "vanishing gradient" doesn't help. I think the question was not too old. Can you help me find it? As the link was in a comment, finding it is particularly hard.

Comment: The site search engine doesn't look at comments, but sometimes Google does.  Try keywords like "shimao relu resnet site:stats.stackexchange.com".

Comment: @AndreSilva good suggestion, I tried to do that without success.

Comment: @whuber good point, tried to do that , but still couldn't find anything. Such a pity, it was a great video....Actually Google did return a few hits that sounded promising, but they were pointing to deleted questions. That would also explain why it doesn't show up in my favorites list - years of burns with the SE search engine have taught me to immediately add to Favorites any question/answer that I find interesting. Thus, I was expecting it to be there, but if the question has been deleted in meantime, that would explain why it's no more among my favorites.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe I found it: [Vanishing gradient vs. dying ReLU?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279209/vanishing-gradient-vs-dying-relu) (youtube video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1YxQ1Od1Y0)).

The reason you probably did not find the comment is because it was not `shimao` who posted, but `Jan Kukacka` (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279209/vanishing-gradient-vs-dying-relu#comment608229_279209)).

> <sub>I recommend watching this talk by Moritz Hardt (youtube.com/watch?v=l1YxQ1Od1Y0) where he explains that ReLU in fact does not solve the vanishing gradient problem. – Jan Kukacka Dec 25 '17 at 20:20</sub>

I found the question putting the following in CV's search box: `vanishing gradient problem ReLU` (it was the first/top Q in the 'relevance' tab).

Comment: ah! That explains the mystery. Thanks a lot :-)